# How to increase the coverage on testing angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, code-coverage, karma-runner, istanbul

So here is my angular directive. Simple one that uses a template url

```
  angular.module('my.directives')
    .directive('userNameDisplay', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          user: '=user',
          status: '=status'
        },
        templateUrl: '/partials/userNameDisplay.html'
      };
    });
```

The spec is as follows. Again it tries to cover all cases.

```
describe('user-name-display', function () {
  var elm, scope;

  beforeEach(module('my.directives', '/partials/userNameDisplay.html'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope;
    elm = angular.element('<user-name-display user="someUser" status="status"></user-name-display>');
    $compile(elm)(scope);
  }));

  it('should have the correct isolate scope values', function () {
    scope.someUser = {
      name: "John",
      color: "blue"
    };
    scope.status = true;
    scope.$digest();

    var isoScope = elm.isolateScope();
    expect(isoScope.user.name).toBe('John');
    expect(isoScope.displayCollaboratorStatus).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should render html within the partial accordingly', function () {
    scope.someUser = {
      name: "John"
    };
    scope.status = false;
    scope.$digest();

    var cBoxSpan = elm.find("span.user-collaborator-box");
    expect(cBoxSpan.length).toBe(0);

    var userNameBox = elm.find("span.user-name");
    expect(userNameBox[0].innerHTML).toBe("John");
  });
});
```

The coverage report looks like the one below. I am using Karma (which uses Istanbul) to get the code coverage. I am trying to increase it to 100%. I can't figure out from the report what I am missing. It says return statement was never hit, but without it, the isolate bindings will not take place. How can I get the coverage to go 100%?

[Here is the image of the report
http://imgur.com/NRzTjyZ](http://imgur.com/NRzTjyZ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll get coverage from a beforeEach block.

Try adding this test (it's identical to your beforeEach code):

```
    it('should compile', function() {
        scope = $rootScope;
        elm = angular.element('<user-name-display user="someUser" status="status"></user-name-display>');
        $compile(elm)(scope);
    });
```